# How can I make this WordPress site more responsive, or fluid?

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make this WordPress site more fluid or responsive so it doesn't overlap in different screen resolutions.

I know the @media attribute, but I'm unsure as to how to implement it within my theme.

Is there a quick "1-2-3" to this, or is it much more intricate?  The site I'm working on is [We Have Issues](http://www.wehaveissues.org) and I'm unsure as to whether or not it's responsive or fluid, but based on THIS screenshot, I'm thinking it's not.

The Social Icons and the Feedback shouldn't be overlapping with the text.

[image]

Thanks for any help anybody can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a quick "1-2-3" to this, or is it much more intricate?

*Much* more intricate I'm afraid.

The theme you are running "Flexibility 3" is not adaptive or responsive.

As @coletrain mentions, you may set the initial viewport size using meta tag (note: this does not make your site responsive, it merely sets the initial scale of your site within the devices veiwport).

To make your website play nice on varied viewport sizes you have a few options:

- Use the **Adaptive** Layout approach, whereby you pick any number of breakpoints for your media queries (those widths at which your websites elements will adjust to new dimensions/layout). Breakpoints are typically chosen to target the more common viewports - e.g. ipad portrait/landscape + iphone portait/landscape.

At each of these breakpoints you would have to specify the new dimensions for all elements on your site that need to scale down (e.g. reducing the width of your #wrap div).

This approach is losing popularity largely because it is fundamentally flawed by only targeting a finite number of viewport sizes, but for those less experienced it may be an accessably low hanging fruit http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/ux-design-qa-with-christian-holst/.

- **Responsive/Fluid**, this method would require you to basically revise many of your websites styles that pertain to the layout/structure and replace the rigid px values with inherently fluid % values.

A VERY crude example here - given a rigid two column layout like your `.postwrap` & `#sidebar` you could change to employ fluid values like:

```
.postwrap {
width: 60%;
}
#sidebar {
 width: 35%;
}
```

Responsive is highly recommended as when implemented correctly, it "future proofs" for the increasingly varied mobile landscape.

- (This is what I would do if I was you) You are using WordPress, arguably one of the most powerful characteristics of this platform is the ability to easily change the Look & Feel of you site by swapping themes.

With the plethora of quality free responsive WP themes out there, there really is no excuse not to have a well designed and mobile friendly theme. Google it.

Also, as for your social icon overlap problem - again use the power of WP to your advantage, try some different plugins if you are looking for a "1-2-3" solution.

**EDIT:** As @stepquick mentions, Ethan Marcottte's Responsive Web Design is a great read (in my experience A Book Apart books tend to be a good "no fluff" resource). Also, if you are wanting to get more hands on than simply implementing a packaged theme, you could also start by using a framework such as foundation http://foundation.zurb.com/ (which is pretty awesome) to build your own.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read my question and offer such a good resopnse, Daniel.  Don't worry about the newbies closing this subject; they're just trying to flex their muscles, as they're new Stack Exchange moderators thinking they're doing something.  This question is FAR from too localized.  But I understand what they're doing ... from a newb's standpoint.

Anyway, this sounds quite intimidating, but necessary ... Yeah, flexibility3 is what I started out with, although I've greatly altered it ... Thanks again for taking the time, Daniel!

Comment: Good point about the distinction between adaptive & responsive. But don't you think a combination of the 2 is best? Because below a certain screen width, 2 columns can become very narrow & tall & difficult to read, to take your css example.

Comment: Ahh yes of course! I guess I didn't mention this explicitly, but a hybrid approach is definitely the way to go in my opinion. This is precisely the functionality provided by Zurbs Foundation as I spruiked previously ;)

Answer (score 1):

To make any site or a wordpress website responsive use css media queries.

Add this to your header.php file above the head tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then in your css file add the media queries

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
 body {
  background: #000;
 }
```

}

Then your website is now responsive of course you will have to style your site depending on each size but the above should get your started. Also check out this [post](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) which explains it more.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very tricky subject. The first question you want to ask is do you find your website having traffic that uses mobile devices?

I would suggest studying your traffic using web analytics, such as google's own web analytics. It gives you information such as browsers, os, technology, location, etc.

Then you really have to decide if it's worth it. There are several tools, and I usually recommend:http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

It's a good book, and the author is a really great guy.

As for doing this fast. There's no fast way to do responsive design the right way. It's about targeting the responsiveness to the proper needs.